# Is this a leafhopper? (Italy)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'm located in Bologna, Italy, in the city center. I found this insect on by bean plants, I think it's feeding on their leaves.

[image: insect1]

[image: insect2]

What is it? [The answer to this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/39874/what-is-the-cause-of-white-spots-on-bean-leaves-and-how-to-solve-the-problem/40921#40921) suggests that it is a leafhopper, but I can't find the exact species. When approached, they seem to jump away.

---

<sub>Altough related to the question I linked, I don't think it's a crosspost, because in that question I want to know primarily what's the solution to the problem of white spots on bean leaves, while here I ask for the exact species in the photo.</sub>